# Spring Kafka error handling for multiple record in the same poll

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm playing with Spring Kafka and error handling (`org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler`) but what it's not clear to me is what happens when `poll` returns multiple records and only one of them is causing exception. As far as I understood, the other records are skipped. How to achieve instead a punctual error handling (e.g. skipping only the affected record and continue with the others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` - it performs a seek on the failed record as well as any other partitions that follow the failed one in the poll results.

When retries are exhausted, the failed record is skipped.

A `RemainingRecordsErrorHandler` (sub-interface of `ErrorHandler` of which STCEH is an implementation) is given the list of remaining records.

[Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current).

With the simple error handler, which only gets the failed record, the remaining records are passed to the listener (as long as transactions are not being used).

Comment: When you say "simple" you mean for example `LoggingErrorHandler`?

Comment: That's an example, but I meant any `ErrorHandler` (that gets just a single record). And I corrected the answer; the remaining records are processed regardless of whether the error handler throws an exception (as long as transactions are not being used).